# UK Refugee Blue Travel document holder. Why can't I travel to Italy anymore?

Tags: air-travel, uk, europe, international-travel, italy

I'm a UK Refugee Blue Travel document holder. Why can't I travel to Italy anymore?

Today they denied me boarding on the plane. I do not know why and how to complain. I paid for my tickets and no one told me about it, even Ryanair, with which I travelled before without any problems.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.lexology.com/library/detail.aspx?g=bda8422e-9057-47c3-973f-360c5e95fa29), Italy started requiring visas for refugee travel document holders in March 2017.

Accordingly, you would need to apply for a visitor visa from the Italian government before traveling to Italy. Many other Schengen countries do not require visas in this situation.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any restriction to get a Schengen by us?(blue passport / travel document holders )

Comment: @Mpoursha I'm not quite sure what you mean. You can apply for a visa at the Italian consulate, and if you're approved, there's no problem with them putting one in your travel document.